Как рассчитать логарифмический colormap?
Требуется раскрасить точки логарифмического графика, но так, как будто они не логарифмические.
Пусть некоторая величина z, отображаемая на графике, может принимать значения от a до b.
Я составил colormap - функцию, которая рассчитывает и возвращает цвет в зависимости от переданного ей числового значения в диапазоне от 0 до 1.
Допустим, так:
table = [
    # x  R     G     B
    [0, 0.01, 0.043, 1],
    [0.2, 0.641, 0.164, 0.725],
    [0.3, 0.988, 0.051, 0.11],
    [0.5, 1, 0.975, 0.5],
    [0.8, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
]

Чтобы рассчитать цвет каждой конкретной точки, я привожу её к нужному диапазону:

и рисую график (здесь и далее псевдокод):
plot(values=z, colormap=colormap) # значения x для цвета рассчитываются внутри построителя

Все точки раскрашиваются правильно:

Теперь я логарифмирую величину z и рисую график:
plot(values=ln(z), colormap=colormap)

График рисуется правильно, однако раскраску хотелось бы сделать такой, какой она была бы без применения логарифмирования.

Поскольку цвета рассчитывает построитель, я могу изменить только colormap.
Поэтому нужно каким-то образом изменить значения первого столбца colormap.
Величина z'=ln(z) может принимать значения от a'=ln(a) до b'=ln(b).
Получаем, что:

Далее я приказал своему домовому эльфу разобраться, как выразить x' при известном x и неизвестных z, a, b, но как бы Кикимер ни старался, он не мог этого сделать.
Например, если сложить эти два уравнения, получится:

Убрать z, a, b никак не получается. Интуиция подсказывает, что решение есть, но я его не вижу.

Приведение к диапазону 0..1 выглядит как (z-a)/(b-a).   Если у вас есть таблица логарифма z, то вы знаете и крайние значения для нормировки.

@MBo, конечно, про приведение к интервалу 0..1 вы правы. Только проблема не с крайними значениями, а с промежуточными. Значения, которые в изначальном графике были крайне малыми, после логарифмирования встали примерно в середину диапазона, и поэтому стали окрашиваться в жёлтый цвет, а не в синий.

@maestro, как устроено приведение существенно влияет на результат. Поправьте вопрос, если вам нужен нормальный ответ.

Примените эту формулу ко всем x из таблицы цветов. Без a и b обойтись невозможно, отображение (логарифм) не линейная функция, границы существенно влияют на результат:
x' = (ln((b - a)x + a) - ln a)/(ln b - ln a)
Или так:
x' = ln((b/a - 1)x + 1)/ln b/a
Вывод:



что
как




Приведение z к x
x = (z - a)/(b - a)z = (b - a)x + a


Диапазоны x и z
x ∈ [0, 1]z ∈ [a, b]


Вводим логарифмы
z' = ln zz' ∈ [ln a, ln b]


Вводим a', b'
a' = ln ab' = ln bz' ∈ [a', b']


Штрихованное приведение
x' = (z' - a')/(b' - a')


Подставляем штрихи
x' = (ln z - ln a)/(ln b - ln a)


Подставляем z
x' = (ln((b - a)x + a) - ln a)/(ln b - ln a)




Я немного порешал и у меня получилось кое-что похожее: x'=(ln(bx-ax+a)-ln(a))/(ln b - ln a). Значения практически сходятся. Я завтра внимательнее рассмотрю ваше решение и отпишусь.

А, так у нас одинаковый результат получился! Да, это то, что нужно, спасибо!

Вам нужно потенцировать (взять экспоненту) первую колонку таблицы. Вот только диапазон 0..1 отобразится  в 1..e, а вам нужно этот 1..e ещё линейно преобразовать в тот диапазон, который у вас после логарифмирования (то, что у вас на графике `0..147), т.е. выполнить для данного примера
x' = (exp(x)-1.0)*147.0 / (e-1.0)


Что-то здесь не то. Как x, так и x', оба должны быть в диапазоне от 0 до 1. Но даже если убрать из вашей формулы умножение на 147, то получается x'=[0. , 0.13, 0.20, 0.38, 0.71, 1. ], однако промежуточные значения наоборот должны "уплотниться кверху". 0.2 должно подпрыгнуть практически до 0.5.

x уплотняется вниз - это значит, что кривая от x станет выпуклой вверх

если для колормапа вам нужно, чтобы шкала по x была равномерной, то придётся сделать интерполяцию цветов по кривой, пересчитав на равномерную сетку.
